# Re importing Excel file to SQL SERVER throught SSIS package

Tags: ssis

I've a SSIS project to import data from Excel file to SQL Server table. But this only append records to my table, I need to add functionality to update existent data in the table, that mean the same excel file can be re imported too many times.

How can I do that or where can I get information
I'm very appreciate

Thanks
Eliana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to use a temporary table and the t-sql MERGE statement. Here's how :

1. Create a temporary table for your session (create table #mytable (...))
2. Import the content of the Excel file into that temporary table
3. Use a MERGE statement to merge the temporary table into your real destination table.

Here is the documentation to T-SQL MERGE statement : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

This example illustrate how to merge both using MERGE :

```
MERGE RealDestinationTable AS target
USING #mytable AS source
ON (target.Id = source.Id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET Name = source.Name
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
    INSERT (Field1, Field2)
    VALUES (source.Field1, source.Field2)
    OUTPUT deleted.*, $action, inserted.* 
        INTO #AnyResultTempTable;
```

Comment: That is good but I got a solution throught SSIS now. thanks anyway

Comment: If your solution is to use a slowly changing dimension, know that MERGE statement is a LOT faster. In fact, it is a lot faster than anything you can do in SSIS to achieve the same result.